# Asp.Net 4.6 How to add a route prefix to controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I need to add one 'pathname' prior to some controllers in order to clarify their purpose.

For example, currently:

`/news/create`,
`/news/edit`,
`/event/create`,
`/event/edit`,

I wish their router could be

`/request/news/create`,
`/request/news/edit`,
`/request/event/create`,
`/request/event/edit`

I tried to add the following code in **RouteConfig.cs**

```cs
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Api",
                url: "request/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

One of controllers **EventController.cs**

```cs
public class EventController : Controller{

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Events eventModel){
          //code
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Events eventModel){
          //code
        }
}
```

Here I meet a problem:

`/request/event/create` **404 error**

`/request/event/edit/1` works!

`/event/create` works!

`/event/edit/1` works!

So, my question is why `/request/event/create` doesn't work and how to fix that?

As far as I know, adding `[Route("request/event/create")]` above Create action could make it work.

---------Update--------

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Api",
                url: "request/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have attribute routing enabled?

Comment: show the other routes in `RouteConfig.cs` and the order in which they are called

Comment: @Nkosi update with my `RouteConfig.cs` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of registered routes is important. Move more specific routes to before general routes

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Api",
            url: "request/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



    }
}
```